# If I want to code in Rust securely, should I code without using pointer arithmetic?

Tags: pointers, rust, pointer-arithmetic

I've read that pointer arithmetic in Rust can be done through the `pointer.offset()` function, but it always has to be implemented in `unsafe code`:

```
fn main() {
    let buf: [u32; 5] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    let mut ptr1: *const u32 = buf.as_ptr();
    unsafe {
        let ptr2: *const u32 = buf.as_ptr().offset(buf.len() as isize);
        while ptr1 < ptr2 {
            println!("Address {:?} | Value {}", ptr1, *ptr1);
            ptr1 = ptr1.offset(1);
        }
    }
}
```

If I want to code in Rust securely, should I code without using pointer arithmetic and just using the corresponding index of an array for example? Or is there any other way?

Comment: The question is rather vague. If you just want to iterate over an array, then you should use `for reference_to_u32 in buf.iter()`, and you should only use unsafe code if you have a reason to do so. There is an infinite number of reasons _why_ you might want to use pointer arithmetic, and in some cases using `pointer.offset()` is the right tool, but without any more specific information we can't really answer this question.

Comment: If you do not have a good and specific reason to work with pointer arithmetics, I suggest writing more idiomatic code instead of an OP. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5558825229e16e7c046261ca60631c53) . If you wish to work with pointer arithmetics, Then it is only guaranteed by developer itself, this is considered as unsafe and that is why you need to write it in unsafe block

Comment: TL;DR: Just don't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> If I want to code in Rust securely

Then you should not use `unsafe`. There are a few legit reasons for `unsafe` (e.g. accessing memory locations that are known and safe to use, e.g. on microcontrollers several registers), but generally you should not use it.

> should I code without using pointer arithmetic and just using the corresponding index of an array for example

Yes. There is no reason (in this specific case) to use `unsafe` at all. Just use

```
for i in 0..buf.len() {
    println!("Value {}", buf[i]);
}
```

This code however is not considered as "rusty", instead use a for-loop

```
for i in &buf {
    println!("Value {}", i);
}
```

Comment: *Then you should not use `unsafe`* — while I agree with the general theme of this answer, saying to **never** use `unsafe` isn't the best. There are times where unsafe code is required (beyond the examples you gave). Writing `unsafe` code correctly is very hard and should be avoided as much as possible, certainly.

Answer (score 7):

Using raw pointers like that is very unlikely<sup>[1]</sup> to be faster than an idiomatic `for` loop over an iterator:

```
fn main() {
    let buf: [u32; 5] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    for val in buf.iter() {
        println!("Address {:?} | Value {}", val as *const u32, val);
    }
}
```

This is also *much* easier to read and doesn't introduce memory unsafety risks.

---

<sup>1</sup> In fact, your code compares two pointer values each iteration, so is likely to be much slower than the idiomatic `for` loop, which can often omit all bounds checks.